# Disable choosing date before today in vuejs-datetimepicker

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, datetimepicker

I am using https://vuejsexamples.com/datetimepicker-component-for-vue-js/ as a datetime picker in my project with vue 3. I don't know how to disable choosing dates befor today. https://codesandbox.io/s/rw3l109yzo?file=/src/App.vue is a code sandbox for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that package supports mechanism to disable choosing dates before today, but I can offer you a hacky solution.

First, we can add `ref="datePicker"` to the DatePicker component:

```
<Datepicker format="YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s" width="100%" ref="datePicker" />
```

Then we can listen to data changes inside that component and add it to `mounted()` with this:

```
  ...
  this.$watch("$refs.datePicker.timeStamp", (new_value, old_value) => {
    this.calendarOnChange();
  });
  ...
```

Then, on that function, we can add class to the disabled days, like this:

```
    calendarOnChange() {
      const days = document.getElementsByClassName("port");
      [...days].forEach((day) => {
        const timestamp = new Date(
          this.$refs.datePicker.year,
          this.$refs.datePicker.monthIndex,
          day.innerText
        );

        const today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (timestamp < today) {
          day.classList.add("beforeToday");
        } else {
          day.classList.remove("beforeToday");
        }
      });
    },
```

The above function checks every single renderred days and compare them to today's date.

Finally, we can add CSS to disable clicking on the dates in which are before today:

```
.beforeToday {
  color: #bbb;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Forked sandbox:

[image: Edit vue-template-forked-lys9xt]

Answer (score -1):

To disable choosing dates before today using the vue3-datepicker component, you need to utilize the `:disabled-dates` prop. This prop allows you to specify a function that determines which dates should be disabled.

Here's how you can achieve this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <date-picker v-model="date" :disabled-dates="disablePastDates" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import DatePicker from "vue3-datepicker";

export default {
  components: {
    DatePicker,
  },
  setup() {
    const date = ref(new Date());

    // Function to disable past dates
    const disablePastDates = (date) => {
      const today = new Date();
      return date < today;
    };

    return {
      date,
      disablePastDates,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```